# Android one button in a linear layout disappears when another one is made gone.

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have 3 elements in a linear layout, from left to right a button and recycler list view and a second button.
I have a third button (“disappear button”) below the linear layout set up to make the first button disappear by setting it to gone. (This third button is just for testing but in the end I want the recycler view's state to send this message. )
When I press the “disappear button” the second button also vanishes and the recycler takes over the entire space allocated to the linear layout.
I fear that I have some fundamental misconception of how the android system works as I have had similar problems in the past.
Is it necessary to somehow redisplay the activity if you change things that effect the lay out?
My main activity looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="7"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:text="First"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvNumbers"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>
        <Button
            android:text="Last"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first_off"
        android:text="turn off first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the java code looks like this

```
package andre.recyclerview_9_20_2017;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView rvContacts = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
        // Create adapter passing in the sample user data
        NumberssAdapter adapter = new NumberssAdapter(this, 4000);
        // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
        rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Set layout manager to position the items
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.first_off);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                firstOff();
            }
        });

    }

    void firstOff(){
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.first);
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RecyclerView RecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //p.weight = 6;
        RecyclerView.setLayoutParams(p);
    }
}

note I have left out the code for the recycler view 
my build.gradle looks like this 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "andre.recyclerview_9_20_2017"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure what you want achive but try setting the button to invisible using button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);, but using View.GONE the button is removed from the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing`

From documentation:

> If set to true, the parent will be used as the anchor when the anchor
>   cannot be be found for layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf, etc.